# jquery remove and add class not work properly at AJAX beforeSend

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with remove/add class with jquery in AJAX beforeSend.
here are the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id">
  <input type="hidden" id="action">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success d-none" id="btn-hide" type="button" disabled>
    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true</span>Saving...
  </button>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Save" id="btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

here are the code when the data submitted:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-info d-none').addClass('btn-success d-inline-block');
        $('#btn').removeClass('btn-info d-inline-block').addClass('btn-success d-none');
    }, 
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-info d-inline-block').addClass('btn-success d-none');
            $('#btn').removeClass('btn-info d-none').addClass('btn-success d-inline-block').val('Save');
            $('#btn-cancel').removeClass('btn-outline-info').addClass('btn-outline-success').text('Cancel');
        }
        $('#form_result').html(html);
    }
});
```

and here is the problem. when updated, the btn-success class should be removed and replaced with btn-info class. the button with id = btn is just work fine. but the button with id = btn-hide (button with spinner before data successfully updated) seems like not working properly. it's still with the btn-success class not btn-info. it should be remove the btn-success and replace it with btn-info class.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/fungsionaris/guru/edit/'+id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-success d-none').addClass('btn-info d-inline-block');
            $('#btn').removeClass('btn-success d-inline-block').addClass('btn-info d-none');
        }, 
        success: function (data) {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-success d-inline-block').addClass('btn-info d-none');
            $('#btn').removeClass('btn-success d-none').addClass('btn-info d-inline-block').val('Update');
            $('#btn-cancel').removeClass('btn-outline-success').addClass('btn-outline-info').text('Cancel');
        }
    });
});
```

so, how to fix it? help please. thank you before

Comment: `beforeSend: function () {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-success d-none').addClass('btn-info
....
        success: function (data) {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-success d-inline-block').addClass('btn-info`

you do the same things in both functions. this should work:

`beforeSend: function () {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-success d-none').addClass('btn-info
....
        success: function (data) {
            $('#btn-hide').removeClass('btn-info d-inline-block').addClass('btn-success`

Comment: still not work. when updated, btn-hide's class beforeSend is still btn-success. it should be btn-info.